# Asp.net core 2.2 response caching, cannot add must-revalidate to cache-control response header

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, responsecache

I am using following setup for response caching:

```
 services.AddMvc(options =>
            {
                
                options.CacheProfiles.Add("HomePage", new CacheProfile()
                {
                    Duration = Constants.HomePageOutputCacheInSeconds,
                    Location = ResponseCacheLocation.Any,
                    VaryByHeader = HttpCacheProfileProvider.CacheKeyHeader

                });
                options.CacheProfiles.Add("Article", new CacheProfile()
                {
                    Duration = Constants.ArticleOutputCacheInSeconds,
                    Location = ResponseCacheLocation.Any,
                    VaryByHeader = HttpCacheProfileProvider.CacheKeyHeader
                });
                options.CacheProfiles.Add("Default", new CacheProfile()
                {
                    Duration = Constants.DefaultOutputCacheInSeconds,
                    Location = ResponseCacheLocation.Any,
                    VaryByHeader = HttpCacheProfileProvider.CacheKeyHeader
                });

                


            }).SetCompatibilityVersion(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

services.AddMemoryCache();
services.AddResponseCaching();
```

And in configure section I set:

```
 app.UseResponseCaching();
```

And controller:

```
[Route("", Name = "DesktopHome")]
[ResponseCache(CacheProfileName = "HomePage", Order = int.MaxValue)]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
```

Everything works well. `Cache-Control:public, max-age:10` is appended in the headers, but I would like to set must-revalidate and max-stale-cache properties as well, and I cant find property to acomplish that.

Property is not available in the CacheProfiles setup, ResponseCacheAttribute, nor in the app.UseResponseCaching setup.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides set in Cacheprofile, you can directly use Response to set them in action:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        Response.GetTypedHeaders().CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue()
        {
            Public = true,
            MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(600),
            MustRevalidate = true,
            MaxStale = true
        };

        return View();
    }
```

[image]

Or you can check [Response Caching Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/middleware?view=aspnetcore-2.2) in official site.

Comment: Properties are not available in the cache profile